# How to stop flash installation prompter in chromium?

Tags: flash, chromium

I want to stop the prompter [at the top of the webpage.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PTkN.jpg)

This is so annoying since I don't want to install flash. And it keeps coming back up for every webpage I visit which has flash content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting chromium with --disable-plugins will kill that, and any other plugin prompts that you're receiving.

It will however, disable any other plugins you currently have installed, and are using.

A chromium issue on code.google.com is available with a similar request:
http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=181403

Comment: This works wells, at least for me, since there's no important plugin. Look into: `about:plugins`. When in Gnome, use `alacarte` to edit the chromium starting command.

Answer (score 0):

Pop into Chromium Settings -> Show Advanced Settings -> Content Settings -> Plugins -> Select Click to Play

This has you clicking any plugin option for flash and should stop the annoying installation popup...

Failing that their is an extension for Chromium called Flashblock which automatically blocks flash content on any website...

Comment: Nope, I had already set my plugins to 'click to play'. BTW, isn't that option only for plugins you have already installed?